# Download and extract file in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm relatively new to Docker and trying to set up a machine that has nginx, MariaDB and PHP-fpm. So far, most things seem to work, except for one: During the execution of `docker-compose up` I want to download an external file and extract it. After successful initialization, I would like to access the extracted files. However, if I check the contents of the destination directory, it's empty.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

[...]

WORKDIR /app

RUN set -ex; \
    curl -o app.tar -fSL "https://www.example.org/app.tar"; \
    tar -xvf app.tar; \
    chown -R www-data:www-data .; \
    rm woltlab_suite.tar

CMD ["php-fpm"]

EXPOSE 9000
```

When running `docker-compose up` it logs this:

```
Step 7/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in b5cd78d398fe
Removing intermediate container b5cd78d398fe
 ---> 8cf4da3b7f31
Step 8/10 : RUN set -ex;     curl -o app.tar -fSL "https://www.example.org/app.tar";     tar -xvf app.tar;     chown -R www-data:www-data .;     rm app.tar
 ---> Running in 8cbc64e06214
+ curl -o app.tar -fSL https://www.example.org/app.tar
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 5394k  100 5394k    0     0  47.4M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 47.4M
+ tar -xvf app.tar
file1.ext
file2.ext
file3.ext
file4.ext
file5.ext
file6.ext
file7.ext
+ chown -R www-data:www-data .
+ rm app.tar
Removing intermediate container 8cbc64e06214
```

I guess, it has something to do with the removal of the container as soon, as it's done?

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mariadb:
    container_name: app_mariadb
    build:
      context: ./docker/mariadb
    environment:
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=${DATABASE_NAME}
      - MYSQL_USER=${DATABASE_USER}
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_ROOT_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - ./docker/mariadb/data:/var/lib/mysql

  php-fpm:
    container_name: app_php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/
    build:
      context: ./docker/php-fpm
    depends_on:
      - mariadb

  nginx:
    container_name: app_nginx
    volumes:
      - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - ./docker/nginx/sites/:/etc/nginx/sites-available
      - ./docker/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./docker/nginx/log:/var/log/nginx/
      - ./src:/app/:ro
    build:
      context: ./docker/nginx
    depends_on:
      - php-fpm
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8443:443"
```

Comment: You need to show us how you're checking for the files.

Comment: I try to access them via the nginx container that is installed next to the php-fpm container. However, a simple `docker exec -it app_php ls -la /app` gives the same result: The app directory is empty.

Comment: 1. Why would a your nginx container be able to access files that are built into the PHP container's image? 2. What does your docker-compose.yml look like?

Comment: Added the docker-compose.yml

Comment: I doesn't matter what you put into `/app` in the image, because you're mounting an external directory overtop of it. Either change where you put those files, or change where you mount that folder.

Comment: Do I need to mount it at all? Or can I create it from the Dockerfile? All I try to achieve is to run `docker-compose up` and the whole app is running.